# radio buttons and javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a form with a radio button group(6 radio buttons),

id's are r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6

and there are 6 hidden tables(display=none;) in this page,

tables id's are t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 .

i want to change the table's dispaly property as inline if a radio button checked,

if,

r1 radio checked show table t1,(other tables should be hidden)

r2 radio checked show table t2, (other tables should be hidden)

r3
   radio checked show table t3,(other tables should be hidden)..so on

i tried to do this with document.getElementById ,but my code did not worked correctly since i am new to javascript. so how to do this?

Comment: are you using jQuery or any other framework??

Comment: Can you at least show some snippets of your HTML, and the code that you have written so far? That would help a lot.

Comment: Or at least try to use Google before posting questions here. This is basic Javascript and will be explained to you in 1001 tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ctrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var index = 0;
for(var ctrl in ctrls) 
{
   if(ctrl.type == "radio") 
    {
        if(ctrl.checked == true) 
        {
          var tbl = document.getElementById("t"+index);
          tbl.setAttribute("style","display:inline");// or other display.
        }
   }
   index++;
}
```

Comment: Ctrls stands for controls.Index is the index of the current radio button checked.And element.setAttribute does exactly what its name tell.

Comment: Yes but events bound to the input tag.

Answer (score 1):

To show and hide tables in a cross-browser compatible manner, you must check the current value of style.display:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDisplay(e){
    element = document.getElementById(e).style;
    element.display == 'none' ? element.display = 'block' : 
    element.display='none';
    swapImage
}
</script>
```

Note that in the code above, this line:

```
element.display == 'none' ? element.display = 'block' :
```

is a equivalent to:

```
if ( element.display == 'none' ) {
    element.display = 'block';
}
else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

You can call `toggleDisplay()` with the table as the parameter when your radio input is selected.

If you encounter these types of issues on a regular basis, you may wish to consider using a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to avoid cross-browser compatibility issues and to avoid writing a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Maybe you should have used standard if-else clause then the ?: operator.

Comment: @Aleksandar: The ternary operator works well in the situation and yields concise code. In your own implementation, feel free to use the format that bests suits you.

Comment: No.I know what does the ?: operator do.But he said that he is a beginner,so I suppose he will easier understand if-else.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/d5hnw/1/

```
<label for="radio1">One</label>
<input name="group" onclick="ShowTable('tb1')" type="radio" id="radio1" />
<label for="radio1">Two</label>
<input name="group" onclick="ShowTable('tb2')" type="radio" id="radio2" />
<label for="radio1">Three</label>
<input name="group" onclick="ShowTable('tb3')" type="radio" id="radio3" />



<table id="tb1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            table 1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="tb2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            table 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="tb3">
    <tr>
        <td>
            table 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


var tables;
window.ShowTable=function(tbl)
{
    if(!tables)
    {
        tables=document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    }

    for(i=0;i<tables.length;i++)
    {
       tables[i].style.display="none";  
    }

    document.getElementById(tbl).style.display="block";

}


table
{
    display:none;
}
```